# oAuth 2 Resource Server Configuration to access an Authorization Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

In order to implement OAuth 2, I have an authorization server and a resource server that exposes APIs. Now, what are the configurations I need to specify in resource server for authorization process? Both are separate independent once.
Can anyone provide sample code or example with explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so in ResourcesServer you will need to specify `@EnabledResourceServer` and use RemoteTokenServices to check you token with Authorization Server

```
/**
 * @author cdov
 */
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices tokenServices() {
        final RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://localhost:8082/auth-service/oauth/check_token");
        return tokenService;
    }
}
```

for more detail see this git repo and readme file :

https://github.com/Dovchiproeng/spring-cloud-security-oauth2-poc/blob/master/spring-cloud-secure-service/src/main/java/com/egen/springcloudsecureservice/config/ResourceServerConfig.java